# OpenCV4Android Kmean doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, k-means

This code should give centers mat with 3 rows and clusterCount number of columns

```
    Mat reshaped_image = imageMat.reshape(1, imageMat.cols()*imageMat.rows());
    Mat reshaped_image32f = new Mat();
    reshaped_image.convertTo(reshaped_image32f, CvType.CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);

    Mat labels = new Mat();
    TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.COUNT, 100, 1);
    Mat centers = new Mat();
    int clusterCount = 5, attempts = 1;
    Core.kmeans(reshaped_image32f, clusterCount, labels, criteria, attempts, Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

I tried same code in C and got centers Mat with 3 rows and clusterCount number of columns.

But in java the Core.kmeans returning 4 columns and cluster number of rows.

```
centers.reshape(3);
```

so now the reshape function doesn't work on centers since the number of rows are depended on cluster size. In C the number of rows are always constant i.e 3.

so in java it gives error

> the number of rows of the matrix cannot be divided by new number of rows

Can someone figure out what is the problem. I even tried [this](https://github.com/badlogic/opencv-fun/blob/master/src/pool/tests/Cluster.java) which is similar to my code and got same error.

**Reference C code :**

```
    cv::Mat reshaped_image = image.reshape(1, image.cols * image.rows);
    cv::Mat reshaped_image32f;
    reshaped_image.convertTo(reshaped_image32f, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);

    cv::Mat labels;
    int cluster_number = 5;
    cv::TermCriteria criteria(cv::TermCriteria::COUNT, 100, 1);
    cv::Mat centers;
    cv::kmeans(reshaped_image32f, cluster_number, labels, criteria, 1, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked :-

I converted bitmap to Mat using bitmapToMat function which returns a RGBA image. so the centers has 4 columns instead of 3.

If you are converting bitmap to Mat and if you need BGR image then do this

```
    Mat imageMat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, imageMat);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```

Cheers