# opencv kmeans only gives black and white image

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Kmeans algorithm only gives black and white outputs

Here is my code

ı couldnt find any solutions to this problem

```
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                ny = new Mat();
                Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, ny);

                Mat bgrImage = new Mat();
                Imgproc.cvtColor(ny, bgrImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR);
                bgrImage.convertTo(bgrImage, CvType.CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);

                Mat reshapedImage = bgrImage.reshape(3,bgrImage.rows()*bgrImage.cols() );

                Mat labels = new Mat();
                Mat centers = new Mat();
                ArrayList<Integer> labelsList = new ArrayList<>();

                int K = 32; // Number of clusters (colors)
                TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + TermCriteria.MAX_ITER, 400, 2.0);

                Core.kmeans(reshapedImage, K, labels, criteria, 1, Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,centers);

                for (int i = 0; i < labels.rows(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < labels.cols(); j++) {
                        labelsList.add((int) labels.get(i, j)[0]);
                    }
                }
                int n = labels.cols() * labels.rows();



                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                    double[] color = centers.get(labelsList.get(i), 0);
                    labels.put(i, 0, color);
                }



                labels.convertTo(labels, CvType.CV_8U);


                Core.normalize(labels, labels, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8UC3);

                Imgproc.cvtColor(labels,labels,Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);


                labels = labels.reshape(3,bgrImage.rows());




             
                Mat blured = new Mat();
                int kernelsz = 5;
                Imgproc.medianBlur(labels, blured, kernelsz);


                Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(blured.cols(), blured.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Utils.matToBitmap(blured, resultBitmap);
                mainview.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
```

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxJd7.jpg)

[final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18BVn.jpg)

I was trying to apply a color quantization with opencv on android studio but my output images only comes out as black and white

UPDATE
I updated the code but output still not colored I cant figure out the problem

```
          bitmap = 
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
        data.getData());
            ny = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, ny);

            Mat bgrImage = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(ny, bgrImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR);
            bgrImage.convertTo(bgrImage, CvType.CV_32F, 1.0 /255.0);

            Mat reshapedImage = 
            bgrImage.reshape(1,bgrImage.rows()*bgrImage.cols() );


            Mat labels = new Mat();
            Mat centers = new Mat();
            ArrayList<Integer> labelsList = new ArrayList<>();

            int K = 4; // Number of clusters (colors)
            TermCriteria criteria = new 
            TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + 
              TermCriteria.MAX_ITER,400, 2.0);

            Core.kmeans(reshapedImage, K, labels, criteria, 1, 
            Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,centers);

            centers.convertTo(centers, CvType.CV_8UC1, 255.0);
            centers.reshape(3);
            List<Mat> clusters = new ArrayList<Mat>();
            for(int i = 0; i < centers.rows(); i++) {
                
            
           clusters.add(Mat.zeros(bgrImage.size(),bgrImage.type())); 
                           
            }

      Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer Integer>();
          
                                                                     
           for(int i = 0; i < centers.rows(); i++) counts.put(i 0);

            int rows = 0;
            for(int y = 0; y < bgrImage.rows(); y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < bgrImage.cols(); x++) {
                    int label = (int)labels.get(rows, 0)[0];
                    int r = (int)centers.get(label, 2)[0];
                    int g = (int)centers.get(label, 1)[0];
                    int b = (int)centers.get(label, 0)[0];
                    counts.put(label, counts.get(label) + 1);
                    clusters.get(label).put(y, x, b, g, r);
                    rows++;
                }
            }

            Mat coloredMat = new Mat();
            coloredMat = clusters.get(3);
            coloredMat.convertTo(coloredMat,CvType.CV_8UC4);

            Bitmap resultBitmap = 
            Bitmap.createBitmap(coloredMat.cols(), 
            coloredMat.rows(), 
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(coloredMat, resultBitmap);
            anaekran.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
```

```
        

Here are  some of the Final output images 
[Final image1][1]
[Final image2][2]
[Final image3][3]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKMxX.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqYCH.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GaTW.jpg
```

Comment: K-Means probably gives you a 1-channel map. Try to apply a color-map or assign random rgb colors to the ids

Comment: yes kmeans returns 1-channel map which theoretically ıt shouldnt . I tried to use Imgproc.cvtcolor to change colorspace of the labels output but it just gives me this error " > Unsupported depth of input image:> 'VDepth::contains(depth)'    > where                                                                                                    >     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S) and ı dont want to just apply colormap to image ı want to use the color centers ı ve got from kmeans.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? It gives you a map with cluster ids. Why should that be more than 1 color? Just use opencv color maps (applyColorMap) to map ids to colors. Or create your own lookup table and use opencv LUT.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d5c/tutorial_py_kmeans_opencv.html in this offical documentation kmeans just gives colored ouputs thats why ı assumed normal kmeans should give 3 channel mat sorry for that I actually new to opencv and ı couldnt appyl your solution on code properly is there any change you can help me with the code

Comment: Ok, for clarification. Labels should be 1 channel and centers should be color values. You have to replace every label pixel by its label's center, but this has to be done in a color image, not in a 1-channel-image.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601631/2393191

Comment: Sorry for the late answer Micka ı was adjusting the code according to link that you provided and ı still have the same problem ı updated main question with 2nd code

Comment: I don't know java syntax well enough to debug your code, sorry.